# JSF Bootsfaces b:selectOneMenu itemValue = null displaying the label value instead

Tags: jsf, bootsfaces

I am using Bootsfaces 1.0.2. The code below, of course, is inside a form. Notice the first selectItem has an itemValue=#{null}. When the page loads, the inputText field with id='test' shows as blank. I then change the dropdown to any other value and the value displays correctly. When I go back to the first option in the drop down with null value, the inputText field displays "-- Seleccione --". What I would expect to see is blank (NULL), right? Or am I missing something here?

```
<b:selectOneMenu value="#{wCPVMController.wcpvm.tipo_v}"
                                id="categoriaVehiculo" label="Categor&#237;a de Veh&#237;culo"
                                required="true" process="@this" update="containerRiesgos test"
                                onchange="ajax:wCPVMController.getRiesgosOpcionales()">
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="-- Seleccione --" itemValue="#{null}" />
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Liviano" itemValue="L" />
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Pesado" itemValue="P" />
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Autobus" itemValue="A" />
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Motocicleta" itemValue="M" />
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Otro" itemValue="O" />

                            </b:selectOneMenu>

<b:inputText id="test" value="#{wCPVMController.wcpvm.tipo_v}"></b:inputText>
```

Comment: Probably fixed in the next version by https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/pull/782/commits/2c87f1608f7fb8ea00b3c5644283a14f874d05ce

Answer (score 0):

Write instead `itemValue=""`

See example here:
https://showcase.bootsfaces.net/forms/selectOneMenu.jsf